# NSstream write encoding issues

Tags: objective-c, tcp, nsstream, actionhero

Im trying to send a string using NSoutputstream , however i cant seem to get the encoding right , using dataWithContentsOfURL works

im using a nodejs TCP server with actionHero library.

it works using netcat and telnet.

```
- (IBAction)sendText:(id)sender {
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_sendTextField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"writing %@",response);

///////////////////////////// this line works/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];


///////////////////////////// this line doesnt work/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//%u returns a non zero value
NSLog(@"%u",[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]);
}
```

i get a null streamError from handle stream Event method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. turns out the problem is in actionHero's on data method where it looks for a /n which is not provided by the ios application. appended a \n and its fine now

Comment: Close please... and can you tag this `actionhero`

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the content of `response`, I can't give you a specific answer as to why NSUTF8StringEncoding doesn't work with it. Generally speaking, however, if there is a byte sequence in your content that is incompatible with UTF-8, you're going to get nil when you call `-dataUsingEncoding:`.

There's a strategy that I learned from reading [Mike Ash's blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-19-character-encodings.html) (look under the section "Fallbacks"), and it's served me pretty well in situations such as yours.

To briefly sum it up, first try using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. If that doesn't work, try using `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. And if that doesn't work, try using `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`. Mike's blog has the rationale for this.